# Need a client that handles multiple IMAP accounts well

Tags: email, imap

Looking for a client that will handle 20+ imap accounts well.
Currently using Thunderbird but its not handling so many accounts well. Maybe there is some settings to change or there is a good client out there to handle many accounts well.

Comment: What troubles are you experiencing when using Thunderbird?

Comment: When using Thunderbird the client can be very slow and it can take a long to send out emails. I should mention that multiple people are using Thunderbird to access the same IMAP accounts but most often at different times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thunderbird should be ok, but if you want to try out some alternatives:

- [Microsoft Outlook 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/)
- [Postbox](http://www.postbox-inc.com/) (based on Thunderbird)
- [Windows Live Mail](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-mail) Desktop

Comment: in general, @Sandeep: you should include links when recommending software...

Comment: Will keep that in mind for next time.

Comment: thanks @SandeepBansal, it is not a big deal that you didn't have links, just a polite thing to do for the OP and other people who view your post, then they know exactly what you're talking about (and say, don't end up on the wrong site or etc).  See you around SU! :)  +1

Comment: +1 for Windows Live Mail. It's fast, easy and free.

Answer (score 1):

[Zimbra](http://www.zimbra.com/products/desktop.html) maybe?

It's supposed to be good. Haven't tried it myself though.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion, but Zimbra is slow to start and is huge on the HDD...at least when I used it several years back.